# JAR location guidance

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am a newbie getting to grips with Java and Eclipse.  Can some one give me some guidance on what JARS should be placed where and why?

For example, what JARS should be placed and referenced in the `JRE\lib` directory?  What JARS should be placed and referenced in the `tomcat\lib` directory?  What JARS should be placed and referenced in the applications `WEB-INF\lib` directory?  Is there any JARS that should be placed and referenced in the `ant\lib` directory?

AJF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JRE\lib` - Intended for Code libraries, property settings, and resource files used by the Java runtime environmen. You can use `JRE\lib\ext` for loading [extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/extensions). jars placed in this path are loaded by the Bootstrap classloader.

`tomcat\lib` - jars placed here are visible to both Tomcat internal classes and to all web applications running on this Tomcat instance. Loaded by the Common classloader (Tomcat). Usually you will use this folder for loading jars common to all the web applications deployed on this instance, for example a JDBC driver.

`WEB-INF\lib` - This is part of your web application and jars placed here are only visible to this web application. Loaded by the web application classloader. This is the correct place to put all the jars required by your web application. Since jars places here are isolated, it allows you to use different versions of the same library in different web applications and prevent collisions.

`ant\lib` - jars placed here are visible when [running Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html).

Comment: This answers my question directly although the other answers are good too.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to include a JAR file to your Eclipse project, you would generally create a 'lib' folder inside the project folder, and put the file in there. You then need to tell eclipse to include it in your class path so your code will compile and run inside eclipse.

To do that:
- Go into the properties of your project
- Select 'Java Build Path' in the left hand column
- Select the 'Libraries' tab in the centre part of the window
- Click the Add JARs button - this will give you a list of your projects in eclipse - expand your project and into the lib folder - your jar will be there.
- Select the JAR, click OK, and OK again out of the properties window.

Your code will now compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Jars are the compressed pre compiled code. What jars you need depend on your application. For example if you are using struts framework you will need struts2-core.jar, or if you are using OGNL you may need ognl.jar.

Location of the Jar's shouldn't matter as long as you inform your application through classpath and buildpath regarding the location of jars.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The location of jars at build time should generally not matter, however their location in runtime (JVM, Tomcat, webapp etc.) is highly significant